# How would i rewrite this method recursivly?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I have this Java code that i would like to rewrite recursivly.

```
String concat(String[] names) {
         String result = "";
         for(String name : names) {
             result += name + ", ";
         }
         return result;
```

Comment: why? and what have you tried?

Comment: Note: 1) Your current version is buggy ... unless a trailing comma is a requirement. 2) Your current version is inefficient.  You should use a `StringBuilder`.  3) Recursion will be less efficient.  4)  There is existing Java SE functionality for doing this kind of thing in Java 8 onwards; e.g. `StringJoiner` and `Collectors.joining`

Comment: @StephenC its not anything of major importance, I'm just trying to do practice problems for class and this was the problem my professor gave that I cant figure out.

Comment: Hint: you probably need a helper function, and the recursion needs to pass an extra index argument.  But your professor wants >>you<< to figure it out.  Not us.  (If you can't ... ask him "OK prof, what is the answer?")

Comment: @ScaryWombat, its a practice problem from my homework that i cant seem to figure out. I think the for(String name : names) is throwing me off.

Comment: Don't you understand what that means?  It simply iterates over the values in the array.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html  and look for the word "enhanced".